# How do I find a Solution Common to Many Linear Systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

So I have the following equation:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} S_n f_n(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z) $$

And then for every particular set $\xi$ of $N$ random $(x,y,z)$ points, $\forall x,y,z \in {\mathbb R} $, I can construct an ${\bf F}_{N \times N}(\xi)$ matrix and a ${\bf g}(\xi)$ column vector and then have a system of equations represented by the matrix equation of the form $ {\bf F}(\xi) \cdot {\bf s} = {\bf g}(\xi)$

So my question is this: Is there a way to find the solution column vector ${\bf s}$ which solves $ {\bf F}(\xi) \cdot {\bf s} = {\bf g}(\xi)$  for multiple $\xi$ sets simultaneously?

Comment: This means the same $s$ solves all those systems, or?

Comment: @mvw Yes, a single ${\bf s}$ that solves all systems at once. Notice that ${\bf s}$ isn't a function of $\xi$.

Comment: if your coefficients are exact elimination should work, if not you might want to solve $A^tA s = A^tb$.

Comment: And by that you mean the $A$ and $b$ are created the way you outlined below?

Comment: Yes, that large system of $kn$ equations in $n$ unknowns. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system#Approximate_solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stack the matrices and vectors top to bottom:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
F_{(1)}\\
\vdots\\
F_{(k)}
\end{array}
\right) s= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
g_{(1)}\\
\vdots\\
g_{(k)}
\end{array}
\right)
\iff
As = b
$$
A solution $s$ must fulfill all the equations from the $k$ subsystems $F_{(i)}s= g_{(i)}$, thus simultaneously.

Comment: The $t$ stands for transpose?

Comment: Okay so to construct the "total" ${\bf F}$ I take each ${\bf F}(\xi)$, transpose it, and pile one on top of the others?

Comment: I usually refer to a vector as a column vector. But you can state your terminology in the answer to make it clear, feel free to explain in any way you feel okay with, I'm listening. :)

Comment: Yeah, $F s = g$. Sorry, I missed that mistake =P. It's the equation of a linear system of equations, so yeah. $Ax=b$.